# Cloudera NODE_MANAGER_UNEXPECTED_EXITS every hour

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I have a cloudera 5.x cluster running in Azure. Everything was running fine, and then a few days ago I started getting "NODE_MANAGER_UNEXPECTED_EXITS" health notifications via email every hour.

This seems to happen on the 43 minute of every hour.

Most of the forms I've come across have suggested outOfMemory errors - though I'm not seeing any of these in the log files. For good measure I've tried upping the java head space memory allocation for NodeManager but this has not solved the problem.

I've stopped all jobs on the cluster - it is essentially sitting idle, but every hour I'm getting these alerts.

Example of the health alert that comes in the email:

```
NODE_MANAGER_UNEXPECTED_EXITS   Role health test bad    Critical    The health test result for NODE_MANAGER_UNEXPECTED_EXITS has become bad: This role encountered 1 unexpected exit(s) in the previous 5 minute(s). Critical threshold: any.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What reasons do you see in the log?

Comment: @cricket_007 - I don't see any errors in the log, which is the frustrating part. Its entirely possible I'm not looking in the correct spot? I'm pulling the logs from cloudera manager UI. I do however see TONS of log entries like this right around the time the health check fails.
`WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Event EventType: FINISH_APPLICATION sent to absent application`

Comment: I think you should be looking at the log files on disk of the node manager rather than within the web portals. You could also try enabling JMX monitoring or GC logging in the JVM opts, which might help you diagnose an OOM issue